# In reactstrap, how do I customize the alert message and visible state from a child component?

Tags: reactjs, components, alert, reactstrap, react-state

I'm using React 16.13.0 and trying to use the reactstrap Alert component to display messages when certain forms are submitted.  I have positioned the Alert component where I want in my App template ...

```
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
          <div className="container">
            <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/add"}>
              Chicommons
            </Link>
            <NavBar />
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div className="auth-wrapper">
          <div className="auth-inner">
            <Alert color="info" isOpen={this.state.visible} >
              I am an alert and I will disappear in 2sec.!
            </Alert>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Add} />
              <Route path="/add" component={Add} />
              <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
              <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
              <Route path="/:coop_id/people" component={AddPerson} />
              <Route path="/:coop_id/listpeople" component={ListPeople} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm having trouble with a couple of things.  One of my form components, src/containers/FormContainer.jsx, has this submit handler ...

```
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Make a copy of the object in order to remove unneeded properties
    const NC = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(coop));
    delete NC.addresses[0].country;

    const url = coop.id ? REACT_APP_PROXY + "/coops/" + coop.id : REACT_APP_PROXY + "/coops/";
    const method = coop.id ? "PATCH" : "POST";
    fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      body: JSON.stringify(NC),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw response;
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const result = data;
        history.push({
          pathname: "/" + result.id + "/people",
          state: { coop: result },
        });
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        /** Would like to place alert here **/

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        err.text().then((errorMessage) => {
          setErrors(JSON.parse(errorMessage));
        });
      });
  };
```

I would like to enable the reactstrap alert with a custom message generated within the above handler.  However, I don't know how to control state of the parent component.  I assume I would have to create some message state in the parent component as well as control the visible state, which I already have, but not sure how to do it from the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a context which enables easy access to the alert anywhere in the application.

`AlertProvider.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback, useContext, createContext } from 'react'

const AlertContext = createContext()

export function AlertProvider(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()


  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen(false)
  }, [setOpen])

  const handleOpen = useCallback(message => {
    setMessage(message)
    setOpen(true)
  }, [setMessage, setOpen])
    
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={[handleOpen, handleClose]}>
      {props.children}
      <Alert color="info" isOpen={open} toggle={handleClose} >
        {message}
      </Alert>
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  )
}


export function useAlert() {
  const context = useContext(AlertContext);
  if (!context)
    throw new Error('`useAlert()` must be called inside an `AlertProvider` child.')

  return context
}
```

Update your `App.js`

```js
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import { AlertProvider } from './AlertProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <AlertProvider>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
            <div className="container">
              <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/add"}>
                Chicommons
              </Link>
              <NavBar />
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Add} />
                <Route path="/add" component={Add} />
                <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
                <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
                <Route path="/:coop_id/people" component={AddPerson} />
                <Route path="/:coop_id/listpeople" component={ListPeople} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AlertProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can then use this in functional components:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useAlert } from './AlertProvider'

function MyComponent() {
  const [open, close] = useAlert();

  useEffect(() => {
    // when some condition is met
      open("Hi") // closable with the toggle, or in code via close()
  })
}
```

This uses an imperative mood to open and close by calling `open()` and `close()`. If you want a declarative mood, the context should instead directly return the `setMessage` and `setOpen` functions.

You can also play around to place the alert component in some other place.

Comment: In the App.js file you are using "AlertProvider".  What is that/where is that defined?

Comment: Oh I see.  Can you also include the imports in that file?  I'm getting a compilation error because React doesn't know where to get "createContext()" from.

Comment: @Dave Done that for you

Answer (score 0):

Just below `function App() {`. add:

```
const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = React.useState("")
```

And change your alert to:

```
<Alert color="info" isOpen={alertMessage!=""} toggle={()=>setAlertMessage("")} >
    {alertMessage}
</Alert>
```

And then I don't know how the rest of your app is laid out, but you want to pass in the `setAlertMessage` function into `handleFormSubmit` as a callback, and call it in/near `setErrors`

Comment: If I'm understanding your solution correctly, you're suggesting passing "setAlertMessage" as a property to all components that want to make alerts?  If I have dozens of components at varying levels of hierarchy, I see this as being really messy.  If this is the only way so be it, but I feel like React would have anticipated this problem and designed a slightly more elegant way of pulling this off.  I coudl be wrong.

Comment: Yeah you understand correctly. :)

In standard React, you pass data down through props, and pass it back up through callback functions.

Passing a function like this around too much can get messy, but often I find it's an issue with trying for too complex an architecture. If really needed though, can use React.Context.

Instead of having one Alert box at the top that all components have to connect to, why not have a reuseable AlertBox component that any other component can add into itself, easily adding a message via prop? Added bonus of the alert being nearer the cause of the issue too.